# Couldnt solve a hspice syntax error

Tags: syntax-error, spiceworks

I'm new to hspice and this is a very basic question.

```
.dc vin VDD VDD 1

.print v(out) par('abs(i(vVDD)*VDD)') v(d2)

.measure dc  avg_leak_low=par('abs(i(vVDD)*VDD)') TRIG v(in) VAL= VDD TD=slew
```

I'm following the syntax but I'm getting an error:

**error**

```
(test.sp:50)syntax error at or before "(" "'abs(i(vVDD)*VDD)'" ")" "TRIG" "v" 
"(" "in" ")" "VAL" "=" "VDD" "TD" "=" "slew"
```

line 50 is the measure statement. VDD and slew are parameters with some values.